# Apply CSS for an HTML generic control like <UL> and <LI> in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, html, css

I don't know how to apply CSS for a HTML generic control like `<UL>` and `<LI>` given  `runat="server"` in ASP.NET. I am finding the `<li>` in a master page from a content page. Once I found that control I want to apply CSS.

```
<ul id="mainMenu" runat="server" style="width:350px;">
    <li id="mainHome" runat="server"><a title="Home" href="#" class="home">Home</a></li>

    <li id="mainManage" runat="server"><a title="Manage" href="#"
                                          class="manage">Manage</a></li>

    <li id="mainEnquiry" runat="server"><a title="Enquiry" href="#"
                                           class="enquiry">Enquiry</a></li>

    <li id="mainReport" runat="server"><a title="Report" href="#"
                                          class="report">Reports</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Please try this,

```
ull.Style.Add("background-color", "Red");
```

Or, I have tested this, will definitely work, please check

```
ull.Attributes.Add("class", "yourClass");
```

**Edit:**
To test this solution I have provided you:

1. make new blank master page and put <ul runat="server" id="ull">
2. then add a new page and use the above master page.
3. make findcontrol ul and put in CSS as I have mentioned in the answer.
4. then run your page, and view source of your HTML page and you will find what you are looking for. Like

Comment: Hai Akthar,
   I use find control to find a list named "home" like this

Control list = this.Master.FindControl("mainMenu").FindControl("mainHome");

now how to aplly css for the control list....